# What is the concept of "tcp-reset" and "icmp-port-unreachable" in the following example?

Tags: linux, centos, iptables, firewall, redhat

example:

```
-p tcp -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset

-p udp -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
```

Comment: Kind of a no-brainer, don't you think? The first one would reject a connection with a [TCP RST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#Connection_termination) packet while the second would generate an [ICMP 3/3 (destination unreachable/port unreachable)](http://www.nthelp.com/icmp.html) packet. Please elaborate on what it is you want to know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The purpose of these is to make a client that tries to connect to these ports realize immediately that the server isn't running, and report the error to the user, rather than keep retrying until it times out. `RST` is a flag sent by a machine when there's no server process listening on a particular TCP port, and `ICMP Port Unreachable` is the analogous response for UDP ports.